# .NET MAUI fails to run on Windows

Tags: maui, .net-maui

The project builds successfully. When trying to start it says there are deployment errors

Error       DEP0600: Deployment failed. EntryPointNotFoundException - Unable to find an entry point named 'IsWow64GuestMachineSupported' in DLL 'kernel32.dll'. [0x80131523]    MonkeyFinder

Update:
Windows 10 Home Version 1703, OS Build 15063.909

Comment: The Windows version is?

Comment: Windows 10 Home Version 1703, OS Build 15063.909

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On doc page [Supported platforms for .NET MAUI apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/supported-platforms), we see requirements to run on Windows 10:

> Windows 10 **version 1809 or higher**, using [Windows UI Library (WinUI) 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/).

Unfortunately, your Windows 10 Home is not a high enough version number.

Update to more recent version and click link above to install WinUI 3.

OR update to Windows 11, if possible.

Comment: Thanks. It was pointed out during installation with a link to another site from Microsoft where my version was still listed as possible option for development although not officially supported. I didn't expect it to not run at all.